# null pointer arrangements of binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I arrange ***n nodes*** in a binary tree, there will always be ***n+1*** NULL pointers. for example, if ***n=3***, then below are the possible arrangements of a Binary tree with ***3 nodes***, all the arrangements have ***4 NULL pointers*** (marked 1,2,3,4)

If I arrange ***100 nodes*** I want to prove arrangement have ***101 NULL pointers*** that's correct.

What approach do I have to prove accurate?

[image: binary tree null pointer]

Comment: this looks like a homework problem, but induction. Prove the statement for n=3 (already done), and then prove that if the statement is true for n=i-1 then it is true for n=i, and thus it is true for all n

Comment: @mackycheese21 Thank you, Could you give me example or any code please?

Comment: You don't need code. You need a written proof.

Comment: Hint for the recursion proof: what happens when you add one more node to a BST containing a least one node ? It takes the place of one null pointer (so one less), but then has two empty children slots, so two more null pointers. So when you add one node, you add one null pointer. For the initialization, if n = 1, it is trivial.

Comment: @m.raynal You are suggesting writing the induction proof in reverse direction - beginning with a tree of size n and adding a node to get a tree of size n+1. This is not very clean. It is cleaner to start the induction step with a tree of size n+1, then identify subtrees of size less than n+1.

Comment: @Stef, I am merely suggesting a weak induction. Some students have not yet learned (or understood alas) strong inductions when they take their first data structure classes. But I agree, the approach you propose is more tree-minded.

Comment: @m.raynal It's not just about being tree-minded; this applies to pretty much all proofs by induction where there is more than one possible object per `n`. If you want to prove "all objects verify some property", and make the assumption that the property is true for all objects of size n; you have to prove the induction step starting with an object of size n+1, and prove that this object verifies the property. If you start with an object of size n, then use it to build an object of size n+1, then prove that *this particular object of size n+1* verifies the property, then (continued)

Comment: (continued) then you haven't proven the property for all objects of size n+1; only for those which can be built in this particular way. Maybe all objects of size n+1 can be built in this way, but then you have to prove that too, which is an extra step in the proof, which is forgotten more-often-than-not and even when it isn't forgotten, it's very error-prone.

Comment: I'm very conscious of this matter, I teach CS in university and read more incorrect inductions than I'd like to. In this case, my comment was merely trying to give a simple intuition without giving the entire proof. This approach imho give the easiest, most straight forward proof: all the student needs to do is take a tree with `n+1` nodes, `n>0`, remove a leaf, use the weak induction hypothesis and conclude.